# Which token do i need to use genesys web-messaging-java sdk?

Tags: genesys-platform-sdk, web-messaging-api

I'm trying to use https://developer.genesys.cloud/api/rest/client-libraries/web-messaging-java/ sdk in a custom java app.
I developed the application following the instructions, however, when I run the application I receive the error: **403 Forbidden.**
Looking at the documentation it seems, I need an access_token, but it is not clear if this is a value I should generate or if there is an authentication process to follow to get the token.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to setup an OAuth Client in Genesys Cloud and obtain an access token first (see https://developer.genesys.cloud/authorization/platform-auth/)

Once you've obtain the access token, the token can be passed in an Authorisation Header when calling the API's.

Tokens by default expire after 24 hours and authorization needs to be re-requested after this time.